# How can I add one column of timedelta and relate it to another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframes, one is group by the user_id and count how many times shows the user_id. Another dataframe is the time and date the user used the service. What I want to do is calculate the timedelta from the 2nd dataframe by the eariliest date - latest date, then add the timedelta into the 1st dataframe, even have one column more to extract the days from the timedelta. I think it might need make a loop to iterate the user_id. I have tried many times, but I cannot have the result I want.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': ['8', '2','5', '1', '10', '4'], 'usage_times':[466,423,401,350,352,333]})
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': ['1', '5','5', '8', '8', '1'], 'Date':['2010-11-16 16:44:52','2010-06-01 00:34:38','2010-05-31 05:01:24','2010-06-01 00:29:30','2010-09-11 23:55:00','2010-08-10 13:00:00']})
```

```
df1:
user_id   usage_times
8         466
2         423
5         401
1         350
10        352
4         333
```

```
df2:
user_id                 Date
1        2010-11-16 16:44:52
5        2010-06-01 00:34:38
5        2010-05-31 05:01:24
8        2010-06-01 00:29:30
8        2010-09-11 23:55:00
1        2010-08-10 13:00:00
```

The codes I have tried is:

```
for users in top_users.user_id:
    latest_trip = df_final[(df_final['user_id'] == users)]['start_at'].max()
    earliest_trip = df_final[(df_final['user_id'] == users)]['start_at'].min()
    usage_period = earliest_trip - latest_trip
    times = days_hours_minutes(usage_period)
    top_users['period'] = top_users.apply(lambda x: list(x) for x in times)
```

What I want to the dataframe become like this:

```
df1:
user_id   usage_times   period                days
8         466           100 days, 00:23:45    100
2         423           15 days, 00:05:45     15
5         401           104 days, 00:23:45    104
1         350           72 days, 00:15:45     72
10        352           40 days, 00:23:45     40
4         333           28 days, 00:43:45     28
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can `merge` df1 and df2, and create the **period** column using `groupby`

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='user_id')
df['period'] = df.groupby('user_id')['Date'].transform(lambda x: x.max() -  x.min() )
df['days'] = df['period'].dt.days
df.drop_duplicates('user_id', inplace=True)
df.drop(columns=['Date'], inplace = True)
df.head()


    user_id usage_times period              days
0   8       466         102 days 23:25:30   102
2   5       401         0 days 19:33:14     0
4   1       350         98 days 03:44:52    98
```

Comment: Thanks so much Terry! Absolutely great idea!! It works very well!!

Answer (score 0):

There are two different steps that must be done.

First, you need to obtain the period. For this you can use `groupby` over df2 and then `aggregate` by the date difference:

```
df2 = df2.groupby(["user_id"]).agg(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())
```

Then, you can `merge` df1 and df2:

```
df_res = df1.merge(df2, on='user_id')
```